# react-native-actionsheet get selected value

Tags: react-native, actionsheet

I am using react-native-actionsheet to show dropdown in iOS, I was able to get the selected index, however, I don't know what is the syntax to get the selected value also.

```
showActionSheet = () => {
  this.ActionSheet.show()
}

handlePress = (buttonIndex,  option) => {
  this.setState({ selected: buttonIndex, Region: options})
}

     <Text style={styles.inputfields} onPress={this.showActionSheet}>Region</Text>
        <ActionSheet
      ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
      title={'Region'}
      options={['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Cancel']}
      cancelButtonIndex={5}
      selectedValue={this.state.Region}
      value={this.state.Region}
      onPress={this.handlePress}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable with your option array

```
const options = ['AUH', 'DXB', 'NE', 'WR', 'AAN', 'Cancel']
```

Pass that variable to your `ActionSheet` component

```
<ActionSheet
  ref={o => (this.ActionSheet = o)}
  title={"Region"}
  options={options}
  cancelButtonIndex={5}
  selectedValue={this.state.Region}
  value={this.state.Region}
  onPress={this.handlePress}
/>;
```

Inside your `handlePress` now you can access your selected value as below

```
handlePress = buttonIndex => {
  this.setState({
    selected: buttonIndex,
    Region: options[buttonIndex]
  });
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont really know about `react-native-actionsheet` but i build

`react-native-universal-actionsheet` its much easier to customize and control.

See here is an example at [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@alentoma/react-native-universal-actionsheet)